# How is a browser overriding my UTF-8 header setting and how do I stop it?

Tags: php, html, css, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I've created a site with a simple CMS system. All text is entered in a standard text box with no fancy ability to add Bold or whatever: you just use raw HTML.

One of the guys contributing to it is using IE7 on an old laptop and (so far as I can tell can't upgrade it or something). Either way, I have set all the pages to use UTF-8 with this in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

The problem is that somehow his browser is forcing it to be "Western (ISO-8859-1)" on entry of the text, so that when his posts are then displayed the UTF-8 makes them look a mess with all those ?s in black diamonds everywhere. I can correct by overriding the view to ISO-8859-1, copying and then pasting back in with the browser on the UTF-8 setting but obviously this is not ideal.

Can anyone tell me what setting on his PC might be causing this override? I've told him how to access the encoding on IE7 and to set it to 'auto' but it's obviously coming back so maybe there's something else.

Comment: Can be IE bug, did he install all MS updates?

Comment: I have asked him to. I will ask again. He's a very busy person and not massively au fait with computers (from what I can tell) and (to top it all) lives to far for me to go directly. Thanks.

Comment: What headers are being sent along with your HTP response, most notably what's the value of the content-type header? (Not the same thing as the content-type meta tag).  You should be able to check this with firebug or web developer toolbar or similar.

Comment: Why are you letting a developer contribute using old technology? Ask him to upgrade, this is the problem, so solve it at the source. Don't make a workaround for this.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - This probably isn't a developer, it's somebody putting text into a CMS. The likelihood is that they're not particularly tech-savvy. Fixing this makes their life easier and the app more robust. That's our job isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The `<meta>` element can only advise the browser what to do - it can't (as far as I know) override any headers being sent by the server. The meta element must appear as early as possible in the `<head>` of the document. You could also try the newer `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

A more robust approach is to [send the header from the server](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php). I'm assuming from the tags on the question that you've got access to PHP. You can set the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) like so:

```
<?php
    header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

You want to put it right at the top of the document, before any HTML is transmitted to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, it's all done in PHP so I can indeed do that. I'll give it a go and see how it works.